# kivy adding 1 every if statement

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Everytime i press the plus_btn num should be added by 1 but it only adds it a single time

i tried using a global varaible and placing the function outside of the class but it didnt work

```
import bidi.algorithm
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class RootWidget(App):
    def build(self):
        inside = FloatLayout()
        label1 = Label(text='hi', font_name='fnnt',pos_hint ={'x':.15, 'y':.15})
        def plus(instance):
            num = 0
            if label1.text == 'hi' and num <= 7:
                num += 1
                print(num)
        plus_btn = Button(text='+', on_press=plus)
        inside.add_widget(plus_btn)
        inside.add_widget(label1)
        return inside



if __name__ == '__main__':
    RootWidget().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `num` variable in your `plus()` method is a local variable for that method and you are resetting it to `0` every time that method is executed. You can correct that in many ways, but a simple way is to just declare a `num` variable in your `RootWidget` class, like this:

```
class RootWidget(App):
    def build(self):
        self.num = 0
        inside = FloatLayout()
        label1 = Label(text='hi',pos_hint ={'x':.15, 'y':.15})
        def plus(instance):
            # num = 0
            if label1.text == 'hi' and self.num <= 7:
                self.num += 1
                print(self.num)
        plus_btn = Button(text='+', on_press=plus)
        inside.add_widget(plus_btn)
        inside.add_widget(label1)
        return inside
```